# Satellizer: Not returning email in login with facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-login, satellizer

I am using https://github.com/sahat/satellizer for adding login with facebook functionality in my angular + laravel ( 5.2) application.

Here is the code I am using in php to call the facebook graph api

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $params = [
        'code' => $request->input('code'),
        'client_id' => $request->input('clientId'),
        'redirect_uri' => $request->input('redirectUri'),
        'client_secret' => Config::get('app.facebook_secret')
    ];

    // Step 1. Exchange authorization code for access token.
    $accessTokenResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/oauth/access_token', [
        'query' => $params
    ]);
    $accessToken = json_decode($accessTokenResponse->getBody(), true);

    // Step 2. Retrieve profile information about the current user.
    $profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
        'query' => $accessToken
    ]);
    $profile = json_decode($profileResponse->getBody(), true);
```

But it is only return id and name in the response. I have tried adding id,name and email as fields in the url as

```
 $profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email', [
        'query' => $accessToken
    ]);
```

Still it is returning only id and name.

I also tried it in Graph API Explorer with the token returned by the above request. It shows proper response.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: updated my answer accordingly. i don´t see any scope parameter being used, so i assume you did not authorize with the email permission.

Comment: I have checked, have given email permission to this app. Also as you can see in my question I have also tried adding field to request url  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email , but still it is returning only id and name

Comment: so did you try it with your own app in the api explorer? do you get the exact same response?

Comment: yes, the token that i have used is the same that i have got from my application after authorizing the application to access my basic profile details and email address. It is showing email in the api explorer but not in the response I am getting in my application

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize with the email permission, of course. And the email has to be confirmed. You can´t be 100% sure to get an email, some users use their phone number to login.

As you can see in your screenshot, you are using the "Graph API Explorer" App in the API Explorer. Switch to your own Application and authorize with the email permission.

This is where it´s being discussed: https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/615

Comment: hi @luschn thanks for replying. I am trying this with my own fb account. I have authorized to access my email address. I have added a screenshot of Fb Graph API explorer, you can see it is returning the email id and other details with the token i obtained through above code.

Comment: added a link to my answer, people are discussing this on github

Answer (score 0):

The field 'email' is only accessible on the User object after the user grants the 'email' permission.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Yht.png)

Answer (score 0):

Had created an issue here https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/701, after investigation by the package author, guzzel request had an issue

Author has replied with this fix. Replace the request with below code.

```
$fields = 'id,email,first_name,last_name,link,name,picture';
$profileResponse = $client->request('GET', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me', [
'query' => [
    'access_token' => $accessToken['access_token'],
    'fields' => $fields
]
]);
```